# Oracle, EXTENDS mus be declared

Tags: oracle, object-oriented-database

I'm trying to create object data types in Oracle.
I have an object type called type_transaction, I use this type of body
EXTENDS functions.
The compiler crashes the following error:
"identifier 'EXTENDS' must be declared.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong

This is type :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_transakcja AS OBJECT
    (
      id_transakcji NUMBER(10),
      data_transakcji DATE,
      pracownika_id REF type_pracownik,
      klient_id REF type_klienta,
      produkt_id REF type_produkt,
      zamowienia k_zamowienie,
      MAP MEMBER FUNCTION odwzoruj RETURN NUMBER,
      MEMBER FUNCTION wartosc_zamowienia RETURN NUMBER,
      MEMBER FUNCTION transakcja(produkty REF type_produkt, ile NUMBER) 
      RETURN NUMBER,
      MEMBER PROCEDURE anuluj,
      MEMBER PROCEDURE zatwierdz
      );

      CREATE TYPE k_zamowienie AS TABLE OF type_sprzedaz;
```

and this is body of type

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY type_transakcja IS

      MEMBER FUNCTION transakcja(produkty REF type_produkt, ile NUMBER) 
      RETURN NUMBER IS
      i INTEGER;
      t k_zamowienie;
      p type_produkt;
      BEGIN
      SELECT DEREF(produkty) INTO p FROM DUAL;
      IF p.ilosc_magazynowa - ile >=0 THEN
      p.ilosc_magazynowa:=p.ilosc_magazynowa-ile;
      t:=SELF.zamowienia;
      t:=extend(1);
      i:= SELF.zamowienia.last();
      t(i).ilosc:=ile;
      t(i).cena:=SELF.wartosc_zamowienia();
      t(i).produkt_id:=produkty;
      RETURN 1;
      ELSE
      RETURN 0;
      END IF;
      END;

      END;
```

Comment: Please try to buid a [MCVE], so that we can try your code, understand the issue and better help you.

Comment: Is it actually saying 'extends', or 'extend'?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure from the limited information you've provided, and what seems to be not quite the actual error you get; but it looks like you're just extending your collection incorrectly.

Assuming `k_zamowienie` is a table type, you're doing:

```
t:=extend(1);
```

instead of:

```
t.extend(1);
```

And you don't really need `i`, and if you do have it your index is going to be one off (as it's based on the size of the original table, not the cloned-and-extended on); you can do:

```
  t(t.last).ilosc:=ile;
  t(t.last).cena:=SELF.wartosc_zamowienia();
  t(t.last).produkt_id:=produkty;
```

But even then you aren't doing anything with `t`, so this seems a bit pointless. Maybe you meant this?

```
  zamowienia.extend(1);
  zamowienia(zamowienia.last()).ilosc:=ile;
  zamowienia(zamowienia.last()).cena:=SELF.wartosc_zamowienia();
  zamowienia(zamowienia.last()).produkt_id:=produkty;
```